# Testing a controller with mocked dependencies in Java Play 2.4

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, playframework-2.4

I am migrating my Java play application from 2.37 -> 2.4.1. In my controller unit tests, I had set up the controller along with its associated mocked dependencies before each test.

It seems that the getControllerInstance method was removed from GlobalSettings in Play 2.4 so now I can't override it to return my controller instance.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PublicRoomsControllerTest extends WithApplication {

    @Mock
    private MyService myService;

    private MyController myController;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        myController = new MyController(myService);

        GlobalSettings global = new GlobalSettings() {

            public <T> T getControllerInstance(Class<T> clazz) {
                return (T) controller;
            }

        };

        start(fakeApplication(global));
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        Result result = route(new RequestBuilder().method(POST).uri("/test"));
        assertEquals(OK, result.status());
    }

}
```

I know I can call the method directly on my controller instance from my test such as:

```
Result result = myController.someMethod();
assertEquals(OK, result.status());
```

This approach seems to work fine until someMethod() relies on form data in the request like

```
 Map<String, String> data = Form.form().bindFromRequest().data();
```

Is there someway for the test to route requests, which may include form data, to use my controller instance?

(I am using Guice, Mockito, and JUnit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out to me here https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/4876. The correct way to do this in Play 2.4.x is to use Helpers.invokeWithContext. So to test my controller with my mocked dependencies I used the following code:

```
RequestBuilder requestBuilder = new RequestBuilder().bodyForm(ImmutableMap.of("userId", 1));
Result result = new Helpers().invokeWithContext(requestBuilder, () -> myController.someMethod());
```

Side note: I beleive invokeWithContext is being changed to a static method in the future.